# Time.now.midnight's susceptibility to time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some daily analytics-style records that track usage on my site, and they work as follows:

- When an 'event' occurs, the site looks for a record that was created at `Time.now.midnight`.
- If such a record is not found, a new one is created, and `created_at` is set to `Time.now.midnight`.

Here's the question - does `Time.now.midnight` get recorded differently depending upon the client's time zone? If so, am I correct in assuming that the above very simple system will break down?

How can I fix it so all analytics records, irrespective of the time zone of the user who triggered their creation, get pegged to one time?

Note: I imagine that setting the `created_at` field to a Date instead of Datetime might have been better in this scenario. Let's assume we're stuck with datetime for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time.now does not get recorded differently based on the clients timezone.

Time.now returns a new time using the system timezone (aka the server)

To use a client specific timezone you have to have a user select their zone and use Time.current or Time.zone.now (which do the same thing)

created_at is usually pinned to UTC, so you shouldn't have any issues their either.
(to change this you need to change Rails.root/config/application.rb)

```
config.time_zone = "whatever you want the ActiveRecord default to be"
```